# How to filter, count sum and loop in the same Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have table like one in the picture (only bigger). [image]

In column A some numbers duplicate. I need to filter column A and count sum of column B. 
Like in the second picture.

[image]

If sum of column B is bigger than 90, then count that as one.
I need to do the same procdure with each unique number in column A.

**In short: I need to know how many unique column A ID's have sum of column B bigger than 90.**

I figured to use "For Each Next", but since I can't figure out how to make code use only unique values, I copied whole column A to different Worksheet, removed duplicates and used it as reference.

Also I do not know how to make code use only filtered cell in formula, so I added cell which count subtotal formula and try VBA code to check for it value instead.

This is what I come up so far:

```
Sub SkaiciuotiCB_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A229")

For Each Cell In rng
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:O2").AutoFilter Field = 8, Criteria1 = Cell.Value
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I793").Value >= 90 Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value + 1
        End If
    Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
    Next
End Sub
```

At this moment I get "Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of Range class failed"

My questions:

How to fix my code.

Additional questions:

1. Is it possible to do everything without helper sheet (order to loop only through unique values in column A).
2. How to count sum of only filtered column B values directly in VBA (without using helper cell with subtotal formula).

Comment: Why don't you try a pivot table? This will automatically give you a list of unique items in A and their corresponding sum of B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after, and if the order of your data is important, but you could try this

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim currentCustomer As String
    Dim currentCustomerDays As Integer
    Dim totalCount As Integer
    
    totalCount = 0

    'Clear sorting rules
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    
    'Sort by first column
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2:A25") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
    'Set sorting arguments and do sort
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B25")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    'run through list
    For i = 2 To 25
    
        If currentCustomer = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value Then
        
            currentCustomerDays = currentCustomerDays + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value
        
        Else
        
            If currentCustomerDays > 90 Then totalCount = totalCount + 1
            
            currentCustomer = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value
            
            currentCustomerDays = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value
            
        End If

    Next i

    If currentCustomerDays > 90 Then totalCount = totalCount + 1
    
    Debug.Print totalCount
    
End Sub
```

This example will run through a table (A1:B25) on sheet 1. Edit as required.

Comment: Thanks code works perfectly (just made small modification and instead of For i = 2 To 25 used For I = 2 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count ). Since I trying to learn VBA, I try to figure and understand code working principle. I am confused with second line of "If currentCustomerDays > 90 Then totalCount = totalCount + 1 (after Next i)" Why it is necessary? Result in loop is not saved after loop ends?

Comment: This is to capture the last occurence of the customer ID. otherwise it will never see the final customer. Another option is to loop through until the first blank cell after your customers, thus ensuring you capture that last customer.